# Prove that there are infinitely many triples $(,,)$ of integers such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=a^3+b^3+c^3$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have already made the observation that since the domain is real numbers, $a^2+b^2+c^2$ the three terms is always positive but $a^3+b^3+c^3$ since its to an odd power can have negative terms implying that at least one of $a$, $b$ or $c$ must be negative.

Comment: a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc) then substitute a^2+b^2+c^2 you get a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c)^3-3(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc) then a^2+b^2+c^2=a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc which doesn't make sense

Comment: yes, I guess I am noticing it now... it was a quick hint (and so faulty!!) as I was in a hurry.

Comment: "at least one of a, b or c must be negative", except if all a,b,c are from {0,1}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like $c= -b$ is good choice. Expression becomes:
\begin{eqnarray}
a^2 + 2b^2 &= &a^3,\\
2b^2& = &a^3 - a^2
\end{eqnarray}

Letting $b=ak$ gives $2k^2 = a-1$, which implies
$$(a,b,c)=(2k^2 +1, 2k^3 + k, -2k^3 -k)$$

satisfies the condition for any integer $k$.

Answer (score 3):

I generated lists of some integer triples that satisfy the equation and noticed what seemed to be two families of related triples. It is easy to verify that the two families of integer triples

$$ (a,b,c) = (-n(2n^2+1),\, (2n^2+1),\, n(2n^2+1)), \tag{1} $$
$$ (a,b,c) = (1-n(n^2-1)/2,\, -(n^2-1),\, 1+n(n^2-1)/2), \tag{2} $$

all satisfy the equation

$$ a^2+b^2+c^2=a^3+b^3+c^3 \tag{3} $$

for any integer $\,n\,$ and therefore there are an
infinite number of integer triple solutions to the equation,
but the solutions for $\,n<0\,$ give the
same unordered triples as for $\,n>0.\,$

Note, for the first family, $\,a+c=0\,$ and for the second family $\,a+c=2$.

Aside from the obvious solution triples
$$ (0,0,0),\,(0,0,1),\,(0,1,1),\,(1,1,1), $$
there are a few other solution triples such as
$$  (-1,-1,2),\, (-95,76,76),\, (-98,-21,99),\,
   (-330,-275,385),\, (-332,123,327), \dots $$
which may have parametrizations. In fact,as
Will Jagy comments, there is an elliptic curve
which gives solutions to equation $(3)$ but an
elliptic curve can have only a finite number of
integer points. The curve is
$$ E: y^2+y = x^3+x^2 \tag{4} $$
with generating point $\,P=(0,0).\,$ Verify that
if $\,(x,y)\,$ satisfies equation $(4)$ then
$\,(y+1,-x,-y)\,$ satisfies equation $(3)$. The
point $\,3P=(1,-2)\,$ gives the solution $\,(-1,-1,2)\,$
and the point $\,7P=(21,-99)\,$ gives the solution
$\,(-98,-21,99).\,$

Comment: there is a family with  $a+b=1$ I suppose one should try $a=b$  as well

Comment: @WillJagy Aside from $\,(-1,2,1),\,(-3,4,-2),\,(-98,99,-21)\,$ what other solutions have $\,a+b=1\,$? Same question for $\,(0,0,0),\,(1,1,0),\,(3,3,-3),\,(76,76,-95)\,$ and $\,a=b\,$?

Comment: I think I got $a+b=1$  by negating one of the variables in sage: E=EllipticCurve([0,1,-1,0,0])
sage: E
Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 - y = x^3 + x^2 over Rational Field
sage: E.integral_points()
[(-1 : 1 : 1), (0 : 1 : 1), (1 : 2 : 1), (2 : 4 : 1), (21 : 99 : 1)]

Answer (score 3):

$$a^2+b^2+c^2=a^3+b^3+c^3\tag{1}$$

Let $b=d-an, c=e+an$ then we get

$-a^3+(2n^2-3dn^2+1-3en^2)a^2+(-2dn+2en+3d^2n-3e^2n)a+e^2+d^2-d^3-e^3=0.$

Finding the integer soluions of simultaneous equation {$-2dn+2en+3d^2n-3e^2n=0, e^2+d^2-d^3-e^3=0$},
we get the only integer soluions $(d,e)=(0,0),(1,1).$

$\bullet\ (d,e)=(0,0)$

Let $b=0-an, c=0+an$ then we get $a = 1+2n^2.$
Hence $(a,b,c)=(1+2n^2, -(1+2n^2)n, (1+2n^2)n).$
This is a sansae's solution.

$\bullet\ (d,e)=(1,1)$

Let $b=1-an, c=1+an$ then we get $a = -4n^2+1.$
Hence $(a,b,c)=(-4n^2+1, 1-(-4n^2+1)n, 1+(-4n^2+1)n).$
This is a Somos's solution.